# Undefined reference when using C++ library from C++

Tags: c++, linker, g++, static-libraries, static-linking

I've been staring on this for hours, but nothing (not even other questions on here) helps. I got a C++ library (unlike most other questions, which link C from C++!) which I'm trying to link from another C++ project.

The library (in `lib/libjttp.a`, as expected by `ld`) has a function `void jtpp::equals(int t1, int t2, std::string msg)`, which I'm trying to call from the other project.

When linking using `g++ -L./lib/ -ljtpp obj/ex1.o obj/preproc/ex1.m.o -o bin/ex1`, the linker keeps throwing:

```
/usr/bin/ld: obj/ex1.o: in function `ex1()':
ex1.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `jtpp::equals(int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:17: bin/ex1] Error 1
```

I checked the ELF dump (using `objdump | c++filt`) and that method is included.

The library is built (from source) in the usual way (I executed these commands in another directory, then copied the resulting library):

```
g++ -Wall -c src/suite.cpp -Isrc/inc/ -o obj/suite.o
ar rcs lib/libjttp.a obj/suite.o
```

When I copy the `suite.o` object file to the other project and link using the object file and not the library (`g++ obj/ex1.o obj/preproc/ex1.m.o suite.o -o bin/ex1`), everything links and the executable is as expected.

What am I doing wrong when linking with the library?

Directory structure (in the new project):

```
 - obj/
    + preproc/
        ~ ex1.m.o
    + ex1.o
 - lib/
    + libjttp.a
```

Comment: You missed to specify that library using `-ljttp` or something similar.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ When linking using `g++ -L./lib/ -ljtpp obj/ex1.o obj/preproc/ex1.m.o -o bin/ex1`, the `-ljttp` is given.

Comment: Apparently the issue was in the order of the arguments: always specify -l before the objects you're trying to link /facepalm